# Find the previous element in other TR, finding it only by class name

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I need when I click on a button to find the nearest TD with a class name searching it in back.

I'll try to be more specific:

My code is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="latoTR" rowspan="5">
    LATO A<br><br> Efficency
    <br>
    <div class="modale">70%</div><br><br> Real time efficency<br>
    <div class="modale">98%</div>
   </td>
   <td class="matriceTR" rowspan="3">A</td>
   <td class="rigaTR" rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
   <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledGreen"></i></td>
   <td>70%</td>
   <td>96%</td>
   <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toHide">
   <td colspan="7">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pieChart01" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
   <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledYellow"></i></td>
   <td>87%</td>
   <td>77%</td>
   <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toHide">
   <td colspan="7">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pieChart02" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
   <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledRed"></i></td>
   <td>93%</td>
   <td>88%</td>
   <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toHide">
   <td colspan="7">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pieChart03" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="matriceTR" rowspan="2">B</td>
   <td class="rigaTR" rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
   <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledGreen"></i></td>
   <td>98%</td>
   <td>83%</td>
   <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toHide">
   <td colspan="7">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pieChart04" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
   <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledRed"></i></td>
   <td>83%</td>
   <td>98%</td>
   <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toHide">
   <td colspan="7">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="pieChart05" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Clicking on some "TD" with class ".toClick" , i need to find the first previuos element with class "matriceTR".

I've tried this:

> $('table .toClick').click(function() {
>   $(this).parents().find('.matriceTR:first') })

but isn't the correct solution.
Help please :)

Comment: try like $(this).closest("table").find(".mitriceTR:eq(0)")

Comment: sorry but isn't correct beacuse with this i found everytime the first "matriceTR" of the table @Swapper

Comment: then try this $(this).closest("tr").find(".mitriceTR:eq(0)")

Comment: @Swapper i need the find the previous and closest "matriceTR" starting from the click, isn't so easy ...

Comment: when you say ***previous element*** I suppose you mean that the element  having class `matriceTR` should be one of the previous ***siblings***  of the currently clicked `.toClick`. If that's not what you mean or you don't understand what "sibling" actually means in HTML hierarchy, I think you should consider re-phrasing it. BTW, it would be clearer if you gave some specific use case in your example (clicking on what `.toClick` and what `.matriceTR` should be found).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".toClick").click(function(){


alert($(this).siblings(".matriceTR").text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="latoTR" rowspan="5">
        LATO A<br><br> Efficency
        <br>
        <div class="modale">70%</div><br><br> Real time efficency<br>
        <div class="modale">98%</div>
      </td>
      <td class="matriceTR" rowspan="3">A</td>
      <td class="rigaTR" rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledGreen"></i></td>
      <td>70%</td>
      <td>96%</td>
      <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down">click me</i></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toHide">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="pieChart01" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledYellow"></i></td>
      <td>87%</td>
      <td>77%</td>
      <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toHide">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="pieChart02" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledRed"></i></td>
      <td>93%</td>
      <td>88%</td>
      <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toHide">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="pieChart03" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="matriceTR" rowspan="2">B</td>
      <td class="rigaTR" rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledGreen"></i></td>
      <td>98%</td>
      <td>83%</td>
      <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toHide">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="pieChart04" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle ledRed"></i></td>
      <td>83%</td>
      <td>98%</td>
      <td class="toClick"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toHide">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="pieChart05" class="pieChartCSS" style="height:250px;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

use `.siblings()`

Comment: Siblings isn't correct because doesn't function in every click but only where the "matriceTR" are on the same TR of the "toClick"